# Python "zfill()" equivalent in OCaml

Tags: python, string, ocaml, leading-zero

I'm a beginner and I have to learn Ocaml for scientific programming. I just have one question: 
Is there an equivalent of Python's `.zfill()` method  in Ocaml to make leading zeros appear in a string?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just out of curiosity, do you need this function for something?

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Answer (score 1):

Strings in OCaml are immutable. That means you're not supposed to modify a string but to create a new one.

There is no zfill function in the standard library, but you can easily make one that way:

```
let zfill s width =
  let to_fill = width - (String.length s) in
  if to_fill <= 0 then s
  else (String.make to_fill '0') ^ s
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's one.

- You can do it easily with build-in functions when you're working with numbers. For instance, to print the number 142857 with leading 0's over 30 characters, use  `Printf.printf "%030d" 142857`.
- You can also make it work with strings if you're fine with using leading spaces instead of leading zeros. For instance, `Printf.printf "%30s" "abcdefg"`.
- Finally if you have to, you can define your own function if need be.

The way the first two options work is by using `Printf`, which is an extremely useful too you really should learn at some point. [Here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) is its documentation for OCaml, but a lot of programming languages have a similar tool.

In `%030d`, we started from `%d` which is a placeholder that will be replaced by an integer (in our case, 142857). We fixed its minimum width to 30 (right-aligned by default) by adding 30 between the two characters: `%30d`. Finally, we added the option to make the leading characters zeros instead of spaces by adding a 0 after the percent sign.

`%30s` is just a placeholder for a right-aligned string of at least 30 characters (with leading spaces, because the options for leading zeros only works with numbers).

---

Now here's a zfill function if for some reason you can't use a well-chosen Printf format in your scenario:

```ml
let zfill n s =
  let length = Bytes.length s in
  if n <= length then
    s
  else
    let result = Bytes.make n '0' in
    Bytes.blit s 0 result (n-length) length;
    result
;;
```

Notice that if performance is an issue (though it probably isn't), this should perform faster than the solution of creating a string of zeros and then concatenating it with `s`, as while `blit` is done "in-place", string concatenation is not, so a temporary string of zeros has to be created. In most scenarios, it shouldn't matter all that much and you can use either option.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks, I didn't realize `Bytes.blit` was a thing. It should be more concise and efficient this way.I updated my answer.